# Is offsetof dereferencing a null pointer

Tags: c++, c, c++11

In looking at how my compiler (VS2015) implements the `offsetof` macro, I see the following implementation:

```
#define offsetof(s,m) ((size_t)&reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((s*)0)->m)))
```

It appears to me that this is dereferencing a null pointer at `((s*)0)->m`.  I understand this to be undefined behavior.  Is this undefined behavior that the compiler specifies more strongly than the language, or is there some nuance to the "never dereference a null pointer" rule that I don't understand?

Comment: The Standard says that `offsetof` does what it says it does. That's all you need to know.

Comment: The implementation can do whatever it wants as long as it works (that is, does what the standard says it should). UB applies to user code only.

Comment: @KerrekSB I understand that `offsetof` is specified in the standard, so it will just work if the implementation is supported by the compiler.  What I want to know is if it is valid for me to write similar code and expect it to work.

Comment: It's not dereferencing a null pointer. It's casting 0 to a pointer t s and taking then dereferencing the m memer of s, then casting it to `char const volatile&` and then taking the address of that (&) and casting it to size_t. In simpler terms, it asks "If an object of type s, was at address 0, what would the address of member m be (because that would be the offset of m in s)". Due to some nuances, it's implementation defined if this'll work. Obviously it will for VS2015 since they're using it.

Comment: @Graznarak No, you can't.

Comment: A simpler example: `char *cptr; printf("%zu\n", sizeof(*cptr));` is not derefencing an undefined variable. It's not dereferencing anything.

Comment: @WeatherVane `sizeof` is an unevaluated context.  The content is never evaluated so there is no undefined behavior as far as dereferencing the null pointer.

Comment: @Graznarak `offsetof` is similar. It's a compiler evaluation, not at runtime.

Comment: @WeatherVane `offsetof` is not an unevaluated context.  It is a standard defined macro that returns a `size_t` that is the offset of the member relative to the beginning of the type.

Comment: A macro is not a function. It is evaluated at compile time.

Comment: A macro essentially does a text substitution.  So, I guess that you could say that a macro is not evaluated at runtime, but it just does a text substitution, so the substituted text is still evaluated.

Comment: @Graznarak the offset is known at compile time. There is nothing to dereference.

Comment: @WeatherVane: You're missing the point. `sizeof(*static_cast<int*>(nullptr))`  does not dereference a null pointer because the expression is not evaluated.  This is called an unevaluated context. Obviously, just `*static_cast<int*>(nullptr)` would be evaluated, and it would be undefined behavior for dereferencing a null pointer. The `offsetof` macro provided is *not* an unevaluated context; after macro text substitution, the compiler *will* evaluate the result; the fact that its result is always the same has nothing to do with whether or not it's evaluated.

Comment: The question is fair: no, we are not allowed to dereference null because the behavior is undefined, full stop. The compiler writers, of course, can peek into what undefined *really* means and do whatever they want. As far as we are concerned, dereferencing a null pointer reformats the entire disk, unless it occurs in this exact expression. Obviously this is a strange implementation of undefined behavior, and in reality there *are* guarantees about dereferencing null as is done here, but we aren't privy to what these are. (1/2)

Comment: @GManNickG why the C tag?

Comment: It's free to fail on other compilers, for example, where `offsetof` is implemented differently because they don't give the same 'undefined behavior' behavior. (2/2)

Comment: @WeatherVane: I didn't add the tag.

Comment: Before I first commented I tried to give a type cast of `*NULL` to `sizeof` in a C program: MSVC would not have it, which why I skewed my first comment.

Comment: Is `*NULL` dereferencing a null _`void *`_? You can't dereference any `void *` (unless, perhaps, you're using GCC or a compiler compatible with it).  If you converted it to `*(int *)NULL`, say, it might have worked.  Or it might still object.

Comment: I was trying it with a `struct` pointer before. I just tried again with this `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(*(char*)NULL));` which works. But I still can't understand the differnce with finding the offset of a `struct` member which is known at compile time. However it was not my question!

Comment: Yes, the code in that particular definition of `offsetof` has undefined behavior if it's evaluated. That just means the behavior is not defined by the standard. The implementation is free to use it, as long as *the implementation* can guarantee that the actual behavior matches what the standard requires for `offsetof`. (If that particular definition of `offsetof` didn't work, the implementation would have to define it differently.)

Comment: @PSkocik casting `0` to a pointer is defined as producing a null pointer. The `->` operator is defined as dereferencing its left-hand operand  . (You claim it dereferences the right-hand operand, which makes no sense)

Comment: @WeatherVane The C tag is because offsetof is a macro defined in the C language.  It turns out that this implementation uses a C++ cast instead of a C cast.